# Header Overlapping underneath image when screen resizes - HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where the header of my site disappears underneath the image banner when the site is resized, and for the life of me, I cannot find out why!

It seems that I am missing some CSS style maybe, I am not sure.

The header is a div with a left and right column which stack when the screen is resized.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>
<link href="assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<header><div class="head-container">
    <div class="head-item-left">1</div>
    <div class="head-item-right">2</div>
    </div>
    </header>
    <div class"top-banner-holder"> 
        <div><img src="images/Southend Furniture Warehouse Store.jpg" class="top-banner-pic" alt="" /></div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
/* Add this as properties to a selector */
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Header style */
.head-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.head-item-left {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 30px;
  flex: 50%;
}

.head-item-right {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 30px;
  flex: 50%;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a one column-layout instead of two-column layout */
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .head-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
    }
.top-banner-pic {
    width:  100%;
    height: 715px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 80% 100%;
            
}
```

[image: Example]